# Page not found after CV Edit

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

After I add my education details on Create Developer CV and Click Save it takes me to a page where it says no page found. Is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong.

## Screenshots

[image]
[image]

## Edit

[image]

## Console

[image]

Comment: Clearly a bug if all you did was click the save button.

Comment: This has happened once before and we couldn't repro. I guess we better try harder... Both reports on Linux and from India... Can you get a capture of the network tab in the developer console when you click save please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Well we're still unable to repro but we've identified the code path that was affected and fixed it. That code path is only reachable if the AJAX request had its query string stripped away. I've pushed the fix to prod so you shouldn't have any more issues.

Comment: It probably got fixed . It doesnt take me anymore to a new page when I click Add education a form opens in that page it works perfectly thanks